# Run command on linux server, but same command's not working on shell script

Tags: linux, shell, hive, hdfs, beeline

I am trying to upload a file to HDFS using the `hdfs dfs -put` command.

When I directly input `hdfs dfs -put 'filepath/filename' 'destination'` on the Linux server, it executes immediately, and the file exists on HDFS.

However, when I write the exact same command in a shell script and execute the script, no error appears, but the file is not uploaded to HDFS. What should I check to resolve this?

I really can't figure out the reason.